# Creating 2 separate table from a table using a condition

Tags: list-manipulation, gathering

I want to make two List/Table(B,C) to separate my values from an existing table(A). To illustrate my question, there is my code:

```
xyrandom[n_] := Table[{RandomReal[{0, 1}], RandomReal[{0, 1}]}, {i, n}];
xyrandomgra = xyrandom[5000];
```

From this point, I want to do that if the value x^2+y^2 < 1, take the x,y value and put it in another table(B) else put the value and put it in a third table(C). I have tried :

```
j = 1;
For[i = 1, i <= 5000,
 If[xyrandomgra[i, 1]^2 + xyrandomgra[i, 2]^2 < 1, {intgraph[j, 1] = xyrandomgra[i, 1], intgraph[j, 2] = xyrandomgra[i, 2] , j++}]; i++]

v = 1;
For[w = 1, w <= 5000,
 If[xyrandomgra[w, 1]^2 + xyrandomgra[w, 2]^2 < 1, (extgraph[v, 1] = xyrandomgra[w, 1] && extgraph[v, 2] = xyrandomgra[w, 2] && v++)]; w++]
```

But I feel I have to "establish" my 2 new tables (intgraph, extgraph) but I wonder how I would do it since I don't know in advance how many input I will have in both tables. What I have done is how I would do it in C or another language but I don't know in Mathematica.

Thanks you very much to enlight me on this subject,

Patrick

Comment: fyi: `RandomReal[{0,1}, {n, 2}]`

Answer (score 9):

```
n = 10^4;

data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}];

split = GatherBy[data, #.# >= 1 &];

ListPlot[split, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Epilog -> Circle[]]
```

[image]